# $resource does not send the get request

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to send an http get request to a host using this code:

```
$scope.completeResult=
    $resource("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily", { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" }, { get: { method: "JSONP" }});

    $scope.finalResult=$scope.completeResult.get({ q: "London", APPID: 'myID' , cnt: 2  });
    console.log( $scope.finalResult);
```

But I get a 404 error. When I checked the `Inspect -> Network` it turns out that it sends the request to: `http://127.0.0.1:27469/views/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?APPID=myID&callback=angular.callbacks._0&cnt=2&q=London`

As you can see, it sends the get request to my localhost rather than real host

```
http://127.0.0.1:27469/views/
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: of course, because of no protocol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily` - add the http:// part to your resource url. It looks like your current url is relative to your site.

so this:

```
$resource("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily", { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" }, { get: { method: "JSONP" }});
```

becomes this

```
$resource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily", { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" }, { get: { method: "JSONP" }});
```